# Add ripple effect to custom compound view

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have created class that extends LinearLayout:

```
public class EventCategoryButton extends LinearLayout {
    private ImageView mIconImageView;
    private TextView mNameTextView;

    public EventCategoryButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initializeViews(context);
    }

    // Constructors with 2 and 3 arguments ...

    private void initializeViews(Context context) {
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.component_event_category_button, this);
        mIconImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.event_category_icon);
        mNameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.event_category_name);
    }

    // Getters and setters...
}
```

and corresponding layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/event_category_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0000"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_category_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background="#0000" />
</merge>
```

When I make request to my server and fetch categories, I loop over each category and create `EventCategoryButton`. And this is the result

[image: home view with EventCategoryButtons]

But when I click on this `EventCategoryButton` there is no ripple effect (since it is LinearLayout). So my question is how to add that ripple effect and attach `onClick` listener?

Answer (score -2):

Use this code to apply default selectable effect (Android 5.0 up) on your main layout.

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Comment: What is my main layout? I do not have `LinearLayout` tag in my `xml` file?

Comment: @clzola You have to use some wrapper layout which wrap things into it. so on that layout you can apply this attribute.

Comment: i have wrapped `ImageView` and `TextView` inside `LinearLayout` and applied `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` but there isn't any effect, nothing happens when I click on it...